# CakePHP 3 - use multiple database connections *without ORM*

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a CakePHP 3.4.6 web application. Due to the fact it's working with legacy (not written in Cake convention) database tables, we have opted to hand-code all of our SQL queries rather than trying to set up `Table` and `Entity` classes. I realise some people will disagree with this, but that's not the point of the question.

I have 3 databases: `app_db`, `users_db`, `extra_db`.

I've configured connections to each one in `config/app.php` such that:

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [], // 'app_db' credentials
    'users_db' => [], // 'users_db' credentials
    'extra_db' => [], // 'extra_db' credentials
];
```

I have a custom Model file located at `src/Model/MyModel.php`. An example of it being used to do a query on **one** of the databases (`app_db`) works like this:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

class MyModel
{
    protected $connection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        $sql = ''; // some SQL query
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll('assoc');
    }
}
```

This works because it gets the connection for `default` which maps to `app_db`.

But, I now want to run a query which needs to get data from `app_db` and JOIN with data from `users_db`.

How do I configure this in the Model so that the SQL will communicate with the other databases?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be, to have another method, which will change connection.

```
public function switchConnection($connection=''){
 $this->connection = ConnectionManager::get(connection);
}
```

end call it for change connection

```
MyModel->switchConnection('app_db');
```

next time you run getData, it will communicate with app_db instead of default.